# Limit client's message in mosquitto

Tags: mosquitto

I need to limit publish count for each client, example 10 message

Mosquitto allow to limit message length but, I don't know how to limit message count

There are variable named max_inflight_messages but what is it?

Comment: On what base you want to limit the count of messages from the clients? They could only publish 10 messages during their entire lifetime, or (let's say) 10 messages/minute?
Anyhow, I think there is no way to do this with the Mosquitto broker config, probably it would be better to implement this in your application's logic (so let's say your subscriber would simply ignore the messages after the limit reached.

Comment: @zgyarmati Thank you for your comment, I need to limit publish about 10 message example for each an hour

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: @romkey In my project, the user hasn't to publish at least 100 messages in a day

Comment: Yes, but **why** do you want to limit the publishing rate, is it just some random arbitrary constraint or does it solve a **real** technical problem?

Comment: @hardillb Because if hacker know my username and password so can publish many messages to broker and broker stoped

Comment: Rate limiting is not the solution to that problem.

Comment: @hardillb Ommm thank you